# Executing cucumber (gherkin scripts) with SOAP UI ?

Tags: cucumber, soapui, bdd

I'm trying to find possibilities for the BDD approach of testing my web services with SOAP UI & Cucumber. Is there any way to achieve this ? Please advise

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use `cucumber`, they why soapUI? Other way, if soapUI is used why Cucumber? What exactly do you need to test?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, both SOAPUI and Cucumber are different test runners. You have to choose between both. Except that SOAPUI provides you http-clients for calling services and Cucumber can contain any tests that use different libraries/clients to do different type of testing.

Presuming that you are thinking to use SoapUI just as http-client for services testing, its better to use Jersey client and use Cucumber/JBehave as BDD runner.

Answer (score 0):

I Do Agree with @I Am's answer. Using Jersey or other httpclient do the needful. In case of jersy with BDD you can use [QAF with Web service plugin](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws). You can use cucumber gherkin or QAF BDD or pure java for test authoring. QAF bdd for web-service may look like below:

```
SCENARIO: My Fist webservice call
META-DATA: {"description":"Just for learning purpose"}

   When user requests '${get.sample.call}'
   Then response should have status 'OK'

END
```

Where, `get.sample.call` will be in properties file holding request details.